# Auto scroll bottom of page uiwebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I wish to once the webview loads

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webBrowser {
    //Scroll to bottom
}
```

Just focus on the bottom so basically just show to bottom of the uiwebview and maybe lock it there so user can't scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you would have to get the content height, i have never done this personally, but [here](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow) is a good place to start:

> Here are some constants available that
>   give the document area of the window
>   that is available for writing to.
>   These will not be available until
>   after the document has loaded and the
>   method used for referencing them is
>   browser specific. The available
>   constants are:
>
> window.innerHeight/Width Provided by
>   most browsers, but importantly, not
>   Internet Explorer.
>   document.body.clientHeight/Width
>   Provided by many browsers, including
>   Internet Explorer.
>   document.documentElement.
>   clientHeight/Width Provided by most
>   DOM browsers, including Internet
>   Explorer.

Then to scroll to the offset you want is done like this:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"scrollTo(0,%d)",scrollPosition];
```

Answer (score 1):

Operations *inside* a webview are controlled with JavaScript, so you'll find various solutions at [Scroll Automatically to the Bottom of the Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page).

Example based on Tho answer (`var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body); scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;`):

#### With UIWebView (deprecated)

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    _ = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body); scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
}
```

#### With WKWebView (iOS 8+)

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body); scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
```