# Scroll Automatically to the Bottom of the Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollto, js-scrollintoview

I have a list of questions. When I click on the first question, it should automatically take me to a specific element at the bottom of the page.

How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: here:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249353/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: **css-only** here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68874831

Comment: Have you tried to use inline anchors? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73257737/452587

Answer (score 1343, accepted):

jQuery isn't necessary. Most of the top results I got from a Google search gave me this answer:

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Where you have nested elements, the document might not scroll. **In this case**, you need to target the element that scrolls and use its scroll height instead.

```
nestedElement.scrollTo(0, nestedElement.scrollHeight);
```

Some additional sources you can take a look at:

- http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=753
- http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/scroll.html
- http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-scroll-bottom/

Comment: Didn't work for me. I did this: `element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight`.

Comment: May 4, 2016: Please note that that the "scrollTo" function is experimental and does not work in all browsers.

Comment: scrollto did not work on my browser, I came across this link below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917921/cross-browser-javascript-not-jquery-scroll-to-top-animation which is very useful because the solutions work across the browsers I tried.

Comment: for a separate element, this is working solution:

document.querySelector(".scrollingContainer").scrollTo(0,document.querySelector(".scrollingContainer").scrollHeight);

Comment: May have to set html, body height to 100% to scroll to bottom

Comment: This should work too: `objectSelector.scrollTo({ top: objectSelector.scrollHeight })`. Understanding that `objectSelector` is the element returned by `document.getElementById`. PD: adding `behavior: 'smooth'` in the `scrollTo` method options set up a predefined scrolling animation.

Comment: `window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight); // didn't work ` `window.scrollTo({top:document.body.scrollHeight}); // work and did the trick`

Comment: In many cases even [**JavaScript isn't necessary**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68874831/8112776) to keep a container bottom-scrolled.

Comment: One of the referred link is broken. Adding the correct linkl. https://www.stackstalk.com/2010/07/javascript-scroll-to-bottom-of-page.html

Comment: hey, I cant scroll all the way to the bottom. It stucks at a particukar postion and can go beyond that. Why is this happening?

Comment: Little did he know, he would become the "quick google search"

Answer (score 194):

To scroll entire page to the bottom:

```js
const scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);
scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;
```

You can view the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9bazc6hx/)

To scroll a specific element to the bottom:

```js
const scrollToBottom = (id) => {
    const element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
}
```

Here is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9bazc6hx/2/)

And here's how it works:

[image]

Ref: [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop), [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight), [clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight)

**UPDATE:** Latest versions of Chrome (61+) and Firefox does not support scrolling of body, see: https://dev.opera.com/articles/fixing-the-scrolltop-bug/

Comment: The solution works with Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE8+. Check out this link for more detail http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html

Comment: @luochenhuan, I've just fixed the sample code by using "document.scrollingElement" instead of "document.body", see above

Answer (score 100):

**Vanilla JS implementation:**

```
element.scrollIntoView(false);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollIntoView

Comment: with jQuery $('#id')[0].scrollIntoView(false);

Comment: at the moment it's Firefox only though

Comment: Works in newer versions of Chrome now, but some of the extra options (like  smooth scrolling) don't seem to be implemented yet.

Comment: I added an empty div at the end of the page and used the id of that div. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Even better: `element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});`

Comment: This should be the right answer! 
Worked on my ionic 1 app

Comment: `{behavior: "smooth"}` isn't very well supported as of 2019 but that's a good and native answer. https://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview

Comment: this answer only works if you add an empty element to end of page? Then isn't the`element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight` answer not needing that?

Comment: Why doesn't that work in a bookmarklet?

Comment: for smooth scroll to bottom:
`element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end' })`

Answer (score 41):

You can use this to go down the page in an animation format.

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight},"fast");
```

Answer (score 39):

one liner to smooth scroll to the bottom

```js
window.scrollTo({ left: 0, top: document.body.scrollHeight, behavior: "smooth" });
```

To scroll up simply set `top` to `0`

Comment: This solution doesn't work in IE. Is there any workout that we can add to make this work in IE as well.

Answer (score 35):

Below should be the cross browser solution. It has been tested on Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE11

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight || document.documentElement.scrollHeight);
```

window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight); doesn't work on Firefox, at least for Firefox 37.0.2

Comment: It *does* work in Firefox 62.0.3, but I've got no clue when they fixed that.

Comment: window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight || document.documentElement.scrollHeight); - The scroll is not smooth. How will make the scrolling smooth @PixelsTech

Comment: You can add options to scrolling

Answer (score 22):

## CSS-Only?!

An interesting CSS-only alternative:

```css
display: flex; 
flex-direction: column-reverse;

  /* ...probably usually along with: */

overflow-y: scroll;  /* or hidden or auto */
height: 100px; /* or whatever */
```

It's [not bullet-proof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page/68874831#comment127102078_68874831) but I've found it helpful in several situations.

**Documentation**: [**`flex`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout), [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction#values), [`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y#values)

---

## <sup>Demo:</sup>

```js
var i=0, foo='Lorem Ipsum & foo in bar or blah ! on and'.split(' ');
setInterval(function(){demo.innerHTML+=foo[i++%foo.length]+' '},200)
```

```css
#demo{ display:flex;
       flex-direction:column-reverse;
       overflow-y:scroll;
       width:150px; 
       height:150px;
       border:3px solid black; }
body{ font-family:arial,sans-serif; 
      font-size:15px; }
```

```html
Autoscrolling demo:&#x1f43e;
<div id='demo'></div>
```

Comment: Be aware that this will create a disconnect between the visual presentation and DOM order when using multiple elements – like paragraphs – to display the text, which will negatively affect users using screen readers. This type of user will not have access to the correct reading order.

Answer (score 19):

Sometimes the page extends on scroll to buttom (for example in social networks), to scroll down to the end (ultimate buttom of the page) I use this script:

```
var scrollInterval = setInterval(function() { 
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
}, 50);
```

And if you are in browser's javascript console, it might be useful to be able to stop the scrolling, so add:

```
var stopScroll = function() { clearInterval(scrollInterval); };
```

And then use `stopScroll();`.

If you need to scroll to particular element, use:

```
var element = document.querySelector(".element-selector");
element.scrollIntoView();
```

Or universal script for autoscrolling to specific element (or stop page scrolling interval):

```
var notChangedStepsCount = 0;
var scrollInterval = setInterval(function() {
    var element = document.querySelector(".element-selector");
    if (element) { 
        // element found
        clearInterval(scrollInterval);
        element.scrollIntoView();
    } else if((document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) != document.documentElement.scrollHeight) { 
        // no element -> scrolling
        notChangedStepsCount = 0;
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    } else if (notChangedStepsCount > 20) { 
        // no more space to scroll
        clearInterval(scrollInterval);
    } else {
        // waiting for possible extension (autoload) of the page
        notChangedStepsCount++;
    }
}, 50);
```

Comment: let size = ($("div[class*='card-inserted']")).length;

($("div[class*='card-inserted']"))[size -1].scrollIntoView();

Comment: @nobjta_9x_tq this will work only if the page is loaded up to the end.

Answer (score 14):

you can do this too with animation, its very simple

```
$('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $('footer').offset().top
   //scrollTop: $('#your-id').offset().top
   //scrollTop: $('.your-class').offset().top
}, 'slow');
```

hope helps,
thank you

Answer (score 13):

You can use this function wherever you need to call it:

```
function scroll_to(div){
   if (div.scrollTop < div.scrollHeight - div.clientHeight)
        div.scrollTop += 10; // move down

}
```

[jquery.com: ScrollTo](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)

Comment: For me, `document.getElementById('copyright').scrollTop += 10` doesn't work (in latest Chrome)... remains zero...

Answer (score 10):

So many answers trying to calculate the height of the document. But it wasn't calculating correctly for me. However, both of these worked:

jquery

```
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 9999});
```

or just js

```
    window.scrollTo(0,9999);
```

Comment: LOL "worked". What if [the document](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) is longer than `9999`?

Comment: @DanDascalescu 99999

Comment: What if the document is longer than 99999?!

Comment: @BrendonMuir If the document is longer than 99999 you can define a javascript variable above the javascript code in the answer that gets the dynamic height of the document and use that variable instead of the hard coded 99999

Comment: Sorry @nviens, I was just being silly, following on from DanDascalescu :D

Answer (score 9):

### Here is a method that worked for me:

#### Expected outcome:

- No scroll animation
- Loads at bottom of page on first load
- Loads on bottom of page for all refreshes

#### Code:

```html
<script>
    function scrollToBottom() {
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    }
    history.scrollRestoration = "manual";
    window.onload = scrollToBottom;
</script>
```

#### Why this may work over other methods:

Browsers such as Chrome have a built-in preset to remember where you were on the page, after refreshing. Just a `window.onload` doesn't work because your browser will automatically scroll you back to where you were before refreshing, AFTER you call a line such as:

```js
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
```

That's why we need to add:

```js
history.scrollRestoration = "manual";
```

before the `window.onload` to disable that built-in feature first.

#### References:

> Documentation for `window.onload`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

> Documentation for `window.scrollTo`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

> Documentation for `history.scrollRestoration`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/scrollRestoration

Answer (score 8):

A simple way if you want to scroll down to a specific element.

Call this function whenever you want to scroll down.

```js
function scrollDown() {
 document.getElementById('scroll').scrollTop =  document.getElementById('scroll').scrollHeight
}
```

```css
ul{
 height: 100px;
 width: 200px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul id='scroll'>
<li>Top Here</li>
<li>Something Here</li>
<li>Something Here</li>
<li>Something Here</li>
<li>Something Here</li>
<li>Something Here</li>
<li>Something Here</li>
<li>Something Here</li>
<li>Something Here</li>
<li>Something Here</li>
<li>Bottom Here</li>
<li style="color: red">Bottom Here</li>
</ul>

<br />

<button onclick='scrollDown()'>Scroll Down</button>
```

Comment: This is not [simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page/58109049#58109049), and requires creating a `scroll` element.

Comment: @DanDascalescu You're right! but my code works I don't think it deserves down vote

Comment: "Works" is not enough. All solutions on this page "work" to some extent. And there's a ton of them. How should a reader decide?

Answer (score 6):

You can attach any `id` to reference attribute `href` of link element:

```
<a href="#myLink" id="myLink">
    Click me
</a>
```

In the example above when user clicks `Click me` at the bottom of page, navigation navigates to `Click me` itself.

Comment: This did not for for me because it changes url and then my angular app redirects to something else!

Answer (score 4):

You may try [**Gentle Anchors**](http://www.angelwatt.com/coding/gentle_anchors.php) a nice javascript plugin.

**Example:**

```
function SomeFunction() {
  // your code
  // Pass an id attribute to scroll to. The # is required
  Gentle_Anchors.Setup('#destination');
  // maybe some more code
}
```

**Compatibility Tested on:**

- Mac Firefox, Safari, Opera
- Windows Firefox, Opera, Safari, Internet Explorer 5.55+
- Linux untested but should be fine with Firefox at least

Answer (score 4):

Late to the party, but here's some simple javascript-only code to scroll **any** element to the bottom:

```
function scrollToBottom(e) {
  e.scrollTop = e.scrollHeight - e.getBoundingClientRect().height;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For Scroll down in Selenium use below code:

Till the bottom drop down, scroll till the height of the page.
Use the below javascript code that would work fine in both, JavaScript and React.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; // (driver is your browser webdriver object) 
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight || document.documentElement.scrollHeight)", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution:

```
 //**** scroll to bottom if at bottom

 function scrollbottom() {
    if (typeof(scr1)!='undefined') clearTimeout(scr1)   
    var scrollTop = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || document.body.scrollTop;
    var scrollHeight = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollHeight) || document.body.scrollHeight;
    if((scrollTop + window.innerHeight) >= scrollHeight-50) window.scrollTo(0,scrollHeight+50)
    scr1=setTimeout(function(){scrollbottom()},200) 
 }
 scr1=setTimeout(function(){scrollbottom()},200)
```

Comment: What... is even going on there? Care you explain your solution? Code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

I have an Angular app with dynamic content and I tried several of the above answers with not much success. I adapted @Konard's answer and got it working in plain JS for my scenario:

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
    <button onClick="scrollToBottom()">Scroll to Bottom</button>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <br>
            <h4>Details for Customer 1</h4>
            <hr>
            <!-- sequence Id -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID">
            </div>
            <!-- name -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
            <!-- description -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea type="text" style="min-height: 100px" placeholder="Description" ></textarea>
            </div>
            <!-- address -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address">
            </div>
            <!-- postcode -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Postcode">
            </div>
            <!-- Image -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <img style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
                <div class="custom-file mt-3">
                    <label class="custom-file-label">{{'Choose file...'}}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Delete button -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click to save">Save</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click to update">Update</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click to remove">Remove</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: #20262E;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

**JS**

```
function scrollToBottom() {
    scrollInterval;
    stopScroll;

    var scrollInterval = setInterval(function () {
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    }, 50);

    var stopScroll = setInterval(function () {
        clearInterval(scrollInterval);
    }, 100);
}
```

Tested on the latest Chrome, FF, Edge, and stock Android browser. Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cbruen1/18cta9gd/16/

Answer (score 2):

I found a trick to make it happen.

Put an input type text at the bottom of the page and call a jquery focus on it whenever you need to go at the bottom.

Make it readonly and nice css to clear border and background.

Answer (score 2):

I gave up with scrollto but instead tried anchor approach:

```
<a href="#target_id_at_bottom">scroll to the bottom</a>
```

Along with this CSS charm:

```
html,
body {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

If there is an ID in any kind of tag at or nearby where you want to scroll to, then all it takes is one line of JavaScript making use of the scrollIntoView function. For example, let's say your element in question is a DIV with the ID "mydiv1"

```
<div id="mydiv1">[your contents]</div>
```

then you would run the JavaScript command

```
document.getElementById("mydiv1").scrollIntoView();
```

No JQuery is necessary at all.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

using reac.js here is the working code

```
        //auto scroll to the bottom 
    useEffect(()=>{
      const chatHolder = document.getElementById('chats-wrapper')
       if(chatHolder) {
          chatHolder.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
       }
  },[chats])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly modern react/typescript-ish utility I am using:

```
export const scrollToBottom = () => {
  // Assume a react re-render may need to happen first
  setTimeout(() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      window.scrollTo({
        top: document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight,
        left: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      })
    })
  }, 3)
}
```

See browser support on smooth scrolling here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo#browser_compatibility

This could probably be turned into a hook:

```
export const useScrollToBottomWhen = (condition: boolean) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (condition) {
      window.scrollTo({
        top: document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight,
        left: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      })
    }
  }, [condition]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

window.scrollTo(0,1e10);

always works.

1e10 is a big number. so its always the end of the page.

Answer (score 1):

If any one searching for Angular

you just need to scroll down add this to your div

```
 #scrollMe [scrollTop]="scrollMe.scrollHeight"

   <div class="my-list" #scrollMe [scrollTop]="scrollMe.scrollHeight">
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will guaranteed scroll to the bottom

**Head Codes**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function scrollToBottom() {
  $('#html, body').scrollTop($('#html, body')[0].scrollHeight);
}
</script>
```

**Body code**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="scrollToBottom();" title="Scroll to Bottom">&#9660; Bottom &#9660;</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. For me at one point in time the div's elements were not loaded entirely and the scrollTop property was initialized with the current value of scrollHeight, which was not the correct end value of scrollHeight.

My project is in Angular 8 and what I did was:

1. I used viewchild in order to obtain the element in my .ts file.
2. I've inherited the AfterViewChecked event and placed one line of code in there which states that the viewchild element has to take into the scrollTop value the value of scrollHeight (this.viewChildElement.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.viewChildElement.nativeElement.scrollHeight;)

The AfterViewChecked event fires a few times and it gets in the end the proper value from scrollHeight.

Answer (score 1):

We can use ref and by getElementById for scrolling specific modal or page .

```
 const scrollToBottomModel = () => {
    const scrollingElement = document.getElementById("post-chat");
    scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;
  };
```

In the modal body you can call above function

```
 <Modal.Body
          className="show-grid"
          scrollable={true}
          style={{
            maxHeight: "calc(100vh - 210px)",
            overflowY: "auto",
            height: "590px",
          }}
          ref={input => scrollToBottomModel()}
          id="post-chat"
        >
```

will work this

Answer (score 1):

**A simple example with jquery**

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop:   $(this).height(),
  });
```

Comment: hmm, does not work with huge <pre>'s in Google Chrome 100 :/ it just scrolls down to the *start* of the <pre>

Answer (score 0):

A picture is worth a thousand words:

The key is:

```
document.documentElement.scrollTo({
  left: 0,
  top: document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

It is using `document.documentElement`, which is the `<html>` element. It is just like using `window`, but it is just my personal preference to do it this way, because if it is not the whole page but a container, it works just like this except you'd change `document.body` and `document.documentElement` to `document.querySelector("#container-id")`.

#### Example:

```js
let cLines = 0;

let timerID = setInterval(function() {
  let elSomeContent = document.createElement("div");

  if (++cLines > 33) {
    clearInterval(timerID);
    elSomeContent.innerText = "That's all folks!";
  } else {
    elSomeContent.innerText = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en", {
      dateStyle: "long",
      timeStyle: "medium"
    });
  }
  document.body.appendChild(elSomeContent);

  document.documentElement.scrollTo({
    left: 0,
    top: document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });

}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  font: 27px Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #ffc;
  color: #333;
}
```

You can compare the difference if there is no `scrollTo()`:

```js
let cLines = 0;

let timerID = setInterval(function() {
  let elSomeContent = document.createElement("div");

  if (++cLines > 33) {
    clearInterval(timerID);
    elSomeContent.innerText = "That's all folks!";
  } else {
    elSomeContent.innerText = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en", {
      dateStyle: "long",
      timeStyle: "medium"
    });
  }
  document.body.appendChild(elSomeContent);

}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  font: 27px Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #ffc;
  color: #333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is "autofocus" somewhere in your code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).