# How can I change CSS style, and focus on element as time goes by?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change background color of `<tr>` with jquery?
Then how can I focus on `<tr>` element with jquery?

**Javascript**

```
$('tr#5').???????? to change background color of <tr#5> to #666666;
$('tr#5').???????? to focus on element "tr#1"; 

.
.
.
$('tr#5').???????? to change background color of <tr#5> back to #ffffff;
$('tr#10').???????? to change background color of <tr#10> to #666666;
$('tr#10').???????? to focus on element "tr#10";
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="border:solid 1px;height:70px; width:500px; overflow-y:scroll;">
    <table height="100" width="400">
    <tr id="5">
        <td>00:00:05</td>
        <td>hello! 5 secs has past</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="10">
        <td>00:00:10</td>
        <td>hello! 10 secs has past</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="10">
        <td>00:00:10</td>
        <td>hello! 10-2 secs has past</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="11">
        <td>00:00:11</td>
        <td>hello! 11 secs has past</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="30">
        <td>00:00:30</td>
        <td>hello! 30 secs has past</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Try looking at the docs
http://api.jquery.com/css/
http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Then provide a more complete example if you still need help

Comment: You can focus only on form elements. And if you want to animate a color animate function with jquery color plugin https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Comment: @jcubic I want to have fixed size table with bunch of comments in it. So I did put scroll bar. But it sometimes changes the color of <tr> which is at very bottom of the table. So I want it to focus(jump to) it

Comment: To jump to it you need to scroll to it, by changing scrollTop property to be `offset().top` of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it's invalid HTML to have non-unique element ids. In fact, before HTML5 it's also invalid to have all-numeric ids. They need to start with a letter followed by any number of letters, numbers, hyphen, colon or period.

That being said, what you're after is the following:

```
$('#5').css('background-color', '#666666');
```

I'm not sure what you you're trying to gain from attempting to focus on a non-interactive element, however, but an interactive element can be focused by using the `.focus()` method.

Comment: What do you mean by 'focusing' in this instance? Do you mean scrolling the row into view or something else? It doesn't mean anything in this instance as a `tr` is non-interactive.

Comment: I want to have fixed size table with bunch of comments in it. So I did put scroll bar. But it sometimes changes the color of <tr> which is at very bottom of the table. So I want it to focus(jump to) it

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page) for hints about how to scroll. Basically you want something like, `$('#element-that-has-scrollbar').scrollBy(0, 50)`.

Comment: I have to scroll it by px? I cannot chose an element to jump to?

Comment: Is the scrollbar on the page, or is it shown on an element with `overflow: scroll`? If the first, then `document.scrollTo(0, $('tr:last').offset().top)` will do.

Comment: I've found an error!!! Please check this update http://jsfiddle.net/N2paw/7/ press button and see the result! it won't scroll and it won't higglight correct line

Comment: Please pull scroll bar down to the bottom and press button. It should jump to 1st line but it won't! http://jsfiddle.net/N2paw/9/

Comment: Why? You said it should highlight/jump to the bottom row.

Comment: I'm so sorry! I was trying to say any line if it's called. it sometimes can be very bottom or very top. It's not fixed. Is it possible? I think you are getting sooo close.

Answer (score 1):

You could use timeouts like this:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    $('tr#5').css('background', '#666666'); 
}, 5000);
setTimeout(function() { 
    $('tr#5').css('background', '#ffffff'); 
    $('tr#10').css('background', '#666666');
}, 10000);
```

Comment: You can apply focus to an element with jQuery by calling `$('tr#5').focus()`

Comment: I tried that but it didn't focus:( please look at this http://jsfiddle.net/N2paw/1/

Comment: I updated your jsFiddle to apply a color to row 11 and scroll to it. I also used classes instead of ids and applied the button click dynamically. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks Can I see the URL?

Comment: Anytime! Happy coding.

Comment: You added animation to jump to the line. what if I don't need animation?

Comment: Here's the jsFiddle jumping to the line without animation: http://jsfiddle.net/N2paw/15/