# How To Remove Awesomium.net Scroll Bars? & Auto Scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, .net, awesomium

I want to remove scroll bars from Awesomium.net web control.

In visual studio defualt web browser you can easily  remove scroll bars like this.

```
Public Sub loadVideo(pLink As String) 

           WebBrowser1.ScrollBarsEnabled = False   

End Sub
```

but i dont know how to do this on Awesomium.net web control.

If there isn't a way to do this on Awesomium.net web control, is there javascript or CSS code i can put to my webpage to achieve those two things?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Awesomium, but it's probably best to remove the scrollbars in CSS. Even if the whole outer web control/page has no scrollbars, the page can have an element in it that takes up all or almost all of the view area and does have scrollbars.

It depends if you want to just hide the graphical scrollbar or disable scrolling. The usual way to stop an element scrolling is to use the CSS `overflow` property, like so:

```
/* Disable scrolling on body */
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
/* Optionally, disable scrolling on everything (not recommended because it's too strong) */
* {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

There's more information searching "css remove scrollbars" or in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page).

Comment: Thanks, this question was posted few month's before and i could not find a solution so i ended using that method.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search for "Remove Awesomium.net Scroll Bars" yeiled the following result:

[How To Hide Scroll Bars In A WPF Webcontrol](http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/2866/how-to-hide-scroll-bars-in-a-wpf-webcontrol.html)

Another few searches, and I found a solution for your second problem:

[How To Inject Javascript On Document Ready Of Any Page](http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/2847/how-to-inject-javascript-on-document-ready-of-any.html)
[Scroll automatically to the bottom of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Comment: i tried that did not work. or i added the code wrong.

Comment: Then edit your post, and let us know what you tried, and how it didn't work.

Comment: These links are broken. Because the content was not provided in the answer, the answer is no longer useful.