# Load a site at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am working on a build for a client of mine and they are wanting this page to load at the bottom of the site, and then the user scrolls up through the site. So basically, the site is built backwards. This site is built on WordPress and I am using Divi, by Elegant Themes as my framework. I have spent the last three hours researching this online and I have also submitted a ticket to Elegant Themes. For the life of me, I cannot figure this out.

I have tried creating an ID at the bottom of the page and I was planning on completing a 301 redirect. This is not working either as the page loads, then scrolls, and completes the scroll too high. I need the page to load with the footer at the very bottom of the page. The link to the dev site is below.

http://dev.narratorgroup.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scroll automatically to the bottom of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Comment: You could use JS to scroll to the bottom of the page. Use a splash/loading screen to cover the animation, then remove the cover once it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple and does not require jQuery or a cover image or an animation. All you have to do is use the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) to select the body element and set it's scroll position to the body's height.

The CSS here is just to simulate overflow on the body.

```js
document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
```

```css
html, body { height: 200%; }
```

---

If you wrap it like this and there is no other document.onload handler defined then you can place this anywhere in the document

```
<script>
    document.onload = function() {
        document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
    }
<script>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the fast reply. So, my ignorance will be exposed, but I am not sure how to access the DOM through this framework. There is a <head> and <body> section within the ePanel for custom scripts. Would I place your JavaScript there? 

Here is a link how the ePanel is laid out. It is towards the bottom under integration. Is this correct?

http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/documentation/theme-options/

Comment: In the HTML file or within the integration <body> section? Sorry for being so green.

Comment: I'll give that a go and let you know. I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: And naturally I dont have access to that file within WordPress.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80435/discussion-between-drew-tuzson-and-humble-rumble).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        var main = function() {
            window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
        }
        $(document).ready(main);
    </script>
```

EDIT:
Requires jQuery.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/f74uk171/