# How to control the scrollbar in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

I have a button on my page, that, when clicked adds a new element to a div on the page. When the div reaches it max height, the scrollbar appears. Now, if I keep pressing the button, new elements will appear, and I'd have to scroll down each time I press the button, in order to see the new element.

How can I move the scrollbar to the bottom after an element is added to the div?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used .scrollTop and it worked.

```
document.getElementById("messagesHolder").scrollTop = document.getElementById("messagesHolder").scrollHeight;
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
 window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

As outlined in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Comment: But If I do something like this : document.getElementById("messagesHolder").scrollTo(0,document.getElementById("messagesHolder").scrollHeight);

The console outputs : Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).scrollTo is not a function

Comment: Or you could give the bottom most element of your page and id and just set up logic to go to it on that occasion. So, <footer id="gotobottom"></footer> if(blah=blahblah){ www.webpage.com/#gotobottom}. This is just pseudo code by the way.