# Scroll down to element with a class name on Vuejs component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component with unordered list and what I want to do is when component is loaded I want the component to be scrolled down to

element with a class name 'actual-month' so it can be visible.

```
<b-card no-body header="<i class='fa fa-align-justify'></i> Unorderd List"  style="height: 680px">
          <b-tabs card pills>
              <b-tab v-for="debt in user_debts"  :title="Debts list"  :key="debt.id" class="card-height">             
                 <table class="table table-sm amortization-header header-fixed">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Month</th>
                        <th>Balance</th>
                        <th>Paid</th>
                        <th>Debt</th>
                        <th>Nominal Interest</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody> 
                    <tr v-for="month in amortization.schedule" :class="{'actual-month' : month.month == amortization.actual_month}">
                      <td>{{month.month}}</td>
                      <td>{{month.balance.toLocaleString()}}<span class="total">€</span></td>
                      <td>{{month.monthly_payment}}<span class="total">€</span></td>
                      <td>{{month.principle}}<span class="total">€</span></td>
                      <td>{{month.interest}}<span class="total">€</span></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </b-tab>
          </b-tabs>
        </b-card>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40737063/1640606

Answer (score 10):

You can use scrollIntoView:

```
mounted: function (){
  var el = this.$el.getElementsByClassName("actual-month")[0];
  el.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Comment: Your solution creates an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of undefined"

Answer (score 4):

There are probably a few ways to do this, but I would place it in a [`mixin`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) so I could reuse it, so:

```
const scroller = {
  methods: {
    scrollToClass(className) {
      // Get the first element with the given class name
      let el = this.$el.querySelector(className)
      // Get the bounding rectangle so we can get the element position position
      let rect = el.getBoundingClientRect()
      // Scroll to the element (using x and y axis)
      window.scrollTo(rect.left, rect.top)
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use it in your `mounted` hook (when `this.$el` first becomes available) like so:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mixins: [scroller],
  mounted() {
    this.scrollToClass('.actual-date')
  }
})
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ha9hm9xe/

Comment: This works if you need to scroll down to an element. If it is somewhere in the top of the page, it just scrolls to topmost part; not to the specific selector with that classname

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Julien's answer, for a lot of use cases, animating automated actions such as jumping to a part of a page, smooth scrolling improves ux:

```
el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers didn't quite work for me - I was getting the following error: `cannot access property scrollIntoView of undefined`. To get around this you can add a `setTimeout`.

Let's suppose you want to scroll to the first element containing the class `invalid` when submitting a form:

```
const someComponent {
  ...
  methods: {
    validateForm() {
      if (formValid) {
        // submit form
        ...
      } else {
        // show errors
        ...
        // and scroll to the first one
        this.scrollToInvalidField();
      }
    },
    scrollToInvalidField() {
      // Without this setTimeout, an "undefined" error is thrown.
      setTimeout(() => {
        let el = this.$el.getElementsByClassName('invalid')[0];
        el.scrollIntoView();
      }, 0);
    },
  },
  ...
}
```

And of course, if you want a smooth scroll `{ behavior: 'smooth' }` can be passed as a parameter to the `scrollIntoView()` function as @digout mentioned in his answer.