# VueJS - How to scroll bottom when data changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my component, I got a messages array.

```
data: function () {
        return {
            messages: [],
            first_load: false
            ...
        }
```

This messages array get initially populated with an Ajax call after the creation of my component. After the data comes from the server I just push it into my messages variable, it paints all messages in the UI amazingly but after it gets pushed I try to scroll bottom my UI so the user watches only the latest content.

```
data.body.data.messages.map((message) => {
    this.messages.push(message)
}
this.scroll_bottom()
```

I noticed that performing a simple javascript scroll bottom line just after pushing my data won't work as the UI gets refreshed asynchronously (When i .push to my array it won't execute next line before syncing the UI), so I ended up adding a timeout and then scrolling bottom, but this is super shameful I think.

My hack:

```
watch: {
    messages:{
        handler: function (val, oldVal) {
            if (!this.first_load) {
                this.first_load = true
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.scroll_bottom()
                }, 1000);
            }
        },
        deep: true
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to leverage this?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think using a timeout is that bad. You can clear the existing timeout and create a new one when the new data comes. Also you can use a debounce function to avoid rapid timeout creation.

Comment: Take a look at Vue life-cycle hooks https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html you can use 'beforeUpdate' & 'updated' hooks for timing your scrolling.

Comment: have you tried nextTick ?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/q/40730116/2813263

Comment: @nipunasudha Thanks for your comment, actually is quite a good thought. I just read the 'updated' method and that is what in theory im looking for. I just tried and it works good, except that for some reason i am doing a lot of changes to my data so it has some problems, but again in theory this is the answer, if you want go ahead and post it.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil, Actually that is the code inside my scroll_bottom() method, hehe thanks but i was looking for the actual logic that will let me scroll bottom after the UI updates itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `updated` life-cycle hook to do something after a DOM update. Take a look at the [official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks).

```
updated: function () {
    //scroll down logic here
}
```

If your `updated` logic is being called rapidly, you can always use a suitable denouncing method to slow down.

Answer (score 3):

I think that watch is the right approach to that, but try using `Vue.nextTick` or `this.$nextTick` (to iterate just current component update cycle) instead of timeout:

```
watch: {
    messages: function (val, oldVal) {
       // DOM not updated yet

       this.$nextTick(function () {
           // DOM updated

           this.first_load = true;
           this.scroll_bottom();
       });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your scrollable div's id is `cont` use the below method to scroll.

```
scroll() {
  document.getElementById('cont').scrollTop = document.getElementById('cont').scrollHeight;
}
```

And you have to call this inside `updated` hook.

```
updated() {
  this.scroll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use v-chat-scroll in div before v-for