# How to go automatically at the bottom of a page without scrolling down when a new div appears in Vue application styled with Tailwind?

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

In my Nuxt/Vue application with Tailwind, by clicking on one `element` I am uncovering the next `element`. It works fine but the user needs to scroll down to see the new element. How can I make my app to go straight away to the bottom of the page to see the new element without scrolling down ??

```
<template>
  <div @click="onClick">
    <Element/>
  </div>
  <div v-if="Section > 0" @click="onClick">
    <Element/>
  </div>
  <div v-if="Section > 1" @click="onClick">
    <Element/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      Section: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      this.Section++
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by referencing the divs and then using `window.scrollTo` to scroll to them (or at the bottom of the page).

Just an example of how you can do it (your code modified):

```
<template>
  <div @click="onClick('section0')" ref="section">
    <Element/>
  </div>
  <div v-if="Section > 0" ref="section0" @click="onClick('section1')">
    <Element/>
  </div>
  <div v-if="Section > 1" ref="section1" @click="onClick('nextSectionRef')">
    <Element/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      Section: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onClick(refName) {
      this.Section++;

      var element = this.$refs[refName];
      var top = element.offsetTop;

      window.scrollTo(0, top);
    }
</script>
```

This will help you to understand it better: https://shouts.dev/vuejs-scroll-to-elements-on-the-page

This also might answer your question: [Scroll to bottom of div with Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730116/scroll-to-bottom-of-div-with-vue-js/57661780)