# Programmatically Scroll External Webpage to Load Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

I am trying to scrape a (very long) webpage for some content.
I am using Python's BeatifulSoup library, but am not limited to Python. The issue I am facing is that the page only loads a small subset of the content, and, as soon as the user scrolls to the top/bottom of the page, more content is loaded.

There is a javascript function that is called when the scroll-bar hits the top/bottom, triggering the server to load more data. Is there a way for me to programmatically scroll through the page, or call the function that gets the page to load more data, so I have all the content available?
I know I could just use VBScript to control the window and scroll, but ideally I am looking for a more elegant solution that allows to me to extract the data and scroll the page at the same time.

Comment: Here from the above answer you get the content of html page fully loaded with all the text in that page.

Answer (score 0):

You can check following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page) OR you can check the net panel and call the same url or method which gets called when page hits the bottom of the page

Comment: This answer specifically tells about the JavaScript part but OP needs pythonic answer of getting html  out from the page.