# Appcelerator Webview scroll to bottom?

Tags: webview, scroll, appcelerator

How do I programmatically scroll a webview to bottom? I am using the webview to show a list of items and I need it to automatically scroll to bottom after the items are loaded so that the user will see the latest items.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with JavaScript within the HTML after the page has loaded.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page