# ScrollToTop is working but i want to scroll down to page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm working on an angular5 app. In that app, I need to go down to the current page based on data. `ScrollToTop` is working fine, I want to go down to the current page. Is there any way like scrollTop in angular5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll Automatically to the Bottom of the Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Comment: Did you try the javascript `document.querySelector('#ComponentId').scrollIntoView();` ?

Comment: Not an answer but just take not of a function called focus, try and make use of that function on the last generated data.

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll to the bottom of the page with this line:

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

If you want to scroll a specific html element, try this one:

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.querySelector(".scrollingContainer").scrollHeight);
```

See also this [demo](http://www.sourcetricks.com/2010/07/javascript-scroll-to-bottom-of-page.html#.WqjDCihuYdU), it can help you.

Answer (score -1):

You can make it using `animate` and `scrollTop` from jQuery as following:

HTML :

```
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
<!-- set the H2 deep down in the page -->
<h2 id="contact">Contact</h2>
```

jQuery :

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(){
    var the_id = $(this).attr("href");
    if (the_id === '#') {
        return;
    }
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop:$(the_id).offset().top
    }, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: is it possible without JQuery

Comment: jQuery is made with javascript, so i'd say it is possible in javascript, but anyway you'll need to use jQuery or Javascript to do this.

Comment: It is not recommended practice to use jQuery and Angular. Not the downvoter

Comment: Ow yeah sorry, @mxr7350 is right, didn't see it was on angular, sry for that :/

Comment: @kevinniel Using jQuery inside an angular app isn't recommended.

Comment: @SivaKrishnaMaddipati You can use third party scroll module like `angular2-infinite-scroll `

Comment: @Laiso thanq for your response, i will try this one.

Comment: @Laiso i want to navigate the control to the bottom of the page, without scroll.