# How to display whole selected element when html page is in the most bottom position?

Tags: css, ace-editor

I am working project with ace-1.3-master template and try to instal button dropdown who I put in most the bottom on the page of HTML.
[image: Display for button dropdown]

My problem is  the button not display fully of it's content and user need to scrolling manually html page to see whole of the button content . how I can make it automaticly without scrolling.

The button position

[image: Display Button problem]

Answer (score 0):

Try use position:fixed; in your css button.
Example:

```
div#myDIV {
    position:fixed;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    left:10px;
    top:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find the solution.
Based  from this question `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page`

I do what @user5978325  was said.
This is the solution
I create a function containing this command

```
 $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight},"fast");
```

and then bind it to first level  from my button element

my code look like this

```
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-white btn-primary"  >others</button>
        <button onclick="scrollToLowest()" data-toggle="dropdown"  class="btn btn-white btn-primary">
        <span class="ace-icon fa fa-caret-down icon-only"></span>
        </button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-success">
      <li>
        <a href="{{url('purchase_detail/download_pdf/'.$app_purchase_id)}}">Print Document PO</a>
        </li>
       <li>
      <a href="{{url('purchase_detail/send_po_to_email/'.$app_purchase_id)}}">Send PO To Email</a>
    </li>   
    <li class="divider"></li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
   function scrollToLowest(){
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight},"fast");
   }
</script>
```

Thanks.