# Scroll Bar not working - Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gam2Q.png)

Attached is the picture of the scroll bar that I would like to move.

I already have a method that is not working. could you please tell me what's wrong?

```
    public static void ScrollPageToEnd(this IWebDriver Driver)
    {
        var maxScrollY = Driver.Scripts().ExecuteScript("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;");
        Driver.Scripts().ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0," + maxScrollY + ")");        

    }
```

Comment: Have you checked to see what maxScrollY is set to?

Comment: Where do you want to move scroll? end of page? or, move to a specific element's location?

Comment: @MahsumAkbas I would like to move it to the end of the page

Comment: @RyanWilson - Yes maxScrollY shows the height. Is there any way I can find out if the scroll height is correct or not?

Comment: @user2320213 Please check out this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `scrollIntoView` function of `JavascriptExecutor` interface to scroll to that location where the Image is.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement("locator of the image")
JavascriptExector js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("argument[0].scrollIntoView");",element)
```

or

we can use method `Scroll(x,y)` to scroll to particular location

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that var maxScrollY is not a string, (`ExecuteScript` returns `object` from what I can recall). Try to save the object `ExecuteScript`to a string with  `string maxScrollY = Driver.Scripts().ExecuteScript("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;").ToString()`.

Also, check with debug the object's value and see what `window.scrollTo(0," + maxScrollY + ")` equals to.

Comment: You're right that `IJavaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript` returns an object, but concatenating a string and an object calls ToSring on that object, so I don't believe that that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

it is working for me:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

i use it as a function to be easier:

```
public void ScrollToEndOfThePage()
        {
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if any JS script is not helping you to scroll, then try MoveToElement?

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("yourLookingId"));
new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(element).Perform();
```

I am using this in a complicated web application with scroll bar and it works perfectly.