# Prevent Ajax Chat from loading to top of page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using a PHP Ajax solution for my chat within my web application. The chat looks very neat, however I am running into a big problem when inside the chat room. I am using a `setInterval` to get new messages but when the interval runs every second the page ends up jumping to the very first message. This happens every single second preventing the user from seeing the latest message. Here is the script I am running:

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    echo
    "<script>

        function ajax() {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

            req.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status==200){
                    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = req.responseText;
                }
            }
            req.open('GET', 'process.php?id=$id',true);
            req.send();
        }
        setInterval(function () {
            ajax();
        }, 1000);
    </script>
";
    ?>
```

Here is my HTML where the content is being loaded:

```
<div class="card bg-sohbet border-0 m-0 p-0" style="height: 100vh;">
        <div id="sohbet" class="card border-0 m-0 p-0 position-relative bg-transparent" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 100vh;" onload="ajax();">
            <div id="content"></div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

I have tried using `setTimeout/clearTimeout`, `event.preventDefault()` and `return false;`. None of these solutions have worked. If you could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Please checkout this video link for an example: https://www.hippovideo.io/video/play/gO83luY-81NfIeSeltBW-Q

Comment: This is because of every time you change the `id="content"`.

Comment: How should I go about editing that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll Automatically to the Bottom of the Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Comment: I would also recommend looking into sockets for this instead of polling the server every second. If you don't want that, you should at least just fetch the new messages since last time you checked (you can go by ID) and just append those to the bottom of the chat list instead of replacing all content in the div.

Comment: By appending the new message after latest message.

Comment: Are you fine with loading the whole data to the chat box every 1 sec? If I may suggest, once you get the data, filter it with your current displayed data, and only prepend/append the new message to your chatbox.

Comment: _Side note:_ Avoid outputting large blocks of HTML/JS in an `echo` using PHP. It's better to end the PHP block `?>` and output the HTML/JS since IDE's usually don't syntax highlight PHP strings correctly, which makes it much harder to debug/read.

Comment: @JerdineSabio  I tried using the append/prepend method and it printed my html as plain text so that solution is out the door

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('content').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', req.responseText);`

Comment: @JerdineSabio I use PHP Storm so it isn't much of an issue. But the potential duplicate didn't have an answer I was looking for. As for the websockets I will take a look into it but I am seeking an immediate solution, `append` didn't give me any luck.

Comment: Did you actually check the suggested duplicate?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yeah I tried using `window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);` and `$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight},"fast");` but they didn't work