# How do I scroll the scrollbar to the bottom?

Tags: angular, perfect-scrollbar

I'm having problem with scrolling scrollbar to the bottom. It works on load correctly when on ngAfterViewInit.

When I add new message it doesn't trigger the scroll, but after adding the second message, it scrolls to the first message. So it looks like I need an delay or something.

```
@ViewChild(PerfectScrollbarComponent, {static: true}) scrollbar?: PerfectScrollbarComponent;


scrollToBottom(): void {
    this.scrollbar.directiveRef.scrollToBottom(0, 200);
 }
```

I created a Stackblitz for that: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjzpgq)

Comment: [This stack overflow answer should help! Best of luck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11715670/10783165)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it with `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.scrollToBottom();
});
```