# How to get the button when clicked go to a certain part of the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like for when after a button has been clicked and the item has been added to the basket for it automatically go to the basket part of the page but I don't quite know how to code this without messing up the rest of the javascript code that is already there for the buttons.

Any code snippets would be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   
</head>
<body>

<header class="main-header">
    <nav class="main-nav nav">
    </nav>
</header>

    <div class="shop-items">
        <div class="shop-item">
            <span class="shop-item-title">Album 0</span>&nbsp;
            <div class="shop-item-details">
<span class="shop-item-price">£12.50</span>
            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO BASKET</button>
        </div>
  
<div class="shop-item">
        <span class="shop-item-title">Album 2</span>&nbsp;
        <div class="shop-item-details">
            <span class="shop-item-price">£14.50</span>
           
            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO BASKET</button>
        </div>
  
  
    <div class="shop-item">
        <span class="shop-item-title">Album 4</span>&nbsp;
        <div class="shop-item-details">
<span class="shop-item-price">£19.50</span>
        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO BASKET</button>
    </div>
    
    </div>
</section>

    <div class="shop-items">
        <div class="shop-item">
            <span class="shop-item-title">Album 6</span>&nbsp;
            <div class="shop-item-details">
<span class="shop-item-price">£19.50</span>
            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO BASKET</button>
        </div>
  
   <div class="shop-items">
        <div class="shop-item">
            <span class="shop-item-title">Album 8</span>&nbsp;
            <div class="shop-item-details">
<span class="shop-item-price">£19.50</span>
            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO BASKET</button>
        </div>
   
    
   
    </div>
</section>
<section class="container content-section">
    <h2 class="section-header">Basket</h2>
  <div class="cart-row">
        <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
        <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
        <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
    </div>
    <p></p> 
<div class="cart-items">
    </div>
    <div class="cart-total">
        <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
        <span class="cart-total-price">£0</span>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" type="button">CHECKOUT</button>
</section>

<script>
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
    ready()
}

function ready() {
    var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
    for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    }

    var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')
    for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
        var input = quantityInputs[i]
        input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
    }

    var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-button')
    for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = addToCartButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked)
}

function purchaseClicked() {
    alert('Thank you for your purchase')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    while (cartItems.hasChildNodes()) {
        cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild)
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function removeCartItem(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    updateCartTotal()
}

function quantityChanged(event) {
    var input = event.target
    if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
        input.value = 1
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText
    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
    addItemToCart(title, price)
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addItemToCart(title, price) {
    var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
    cartRow.classList.add('cart-row')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title')
    for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
            alert('This item is already added to the cart')
            return
        }
    }
    var cartRowContents = `
        <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <span class="cart-item-title">${title}</span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-price cart-column">${price}</span>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`
    cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents
    cartItems.append(cartRow)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
}

function updateCartTotal() {
var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
var total = 0
for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
    var cartRow = cartRows[i]
    var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
    var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
    var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('£', ''))
    var quantity = quantityElement.value
    total = total + (price * quantity)
}
total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100
document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = '£' + total.toFixed(2)
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean to scroll to that element in smoothly?

You can use [scrollIntoView()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   
</head>
<body>

<header class="main-header">
    <nav class="main-nav nav">
    </nav>
</header>

    <div class="shop-items">
        <div class="shop-item">
            <span class="shop-item-title">Album 0</span>&nbsp;
            <div class="shop-item-details">
<span class="shop-item-price">£12.50</span>
            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO BASKET</button>
        </div>
  
<div class="shop-item">
        <span class="shop-item-title">Album 2</span>&nbsp;
        <div class="shop-item-details">
            <span class="shop-item-price">£14.50</span>
           
            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO BASKET</button>
        </div>
  
  
    <div class="shop-item">
        <span class="shop-item-title">Album 4</span>&nbsp;
        <div class="shop-item-details">
<span class="shop-item-price">£19.50</span>
        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO BASKET</button>
    </div>
    
    </div>
</section>

    <div class="shop-items">
        <div class="shop-item">
            <span class="shop-item-title">Album 6</span>&nbsp;
            <div class="shop-item-details">
<span class="shop-item-price">£19.50</span>
            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO BASKET</button>
        </div>
  
   <div class="shop-items">
        <div class="shop-item">
            <span class="shop-item-title">Album 8</span>&nbsp;
            <div class="shop-item-details">
<span class="shop-item-price">£19.50</span>
            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO BASKET</button>
        </div>
   
    
   
    </div>
</section>
<section class="container content-section">
    <h2 class="section-header">Basket</h2>
  <div class="cart-row">
        <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
        <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
        <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
    </div>
    <p></p> 
<div class="cart-items">
    </div>
    <div class="cart-total">
        <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
        <span class="cart-total-price">£0</span>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" type="button">CHECKOUT</button>
</section>

<script>
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
    ready()
}

function ready() {
    var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
    for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    }

    var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')
    for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
        var input = quantityInputs[i]
        input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
    }

    var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-button')
    for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = addToCartButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked)
}

function purchaseClicked() {
    alert('Thank you for your purchase')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    while (cartItems.hasChildNodes()) {
        cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild)
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function removeCartItem(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    updateCartTotal()
}

function quantityChanged(event) {
    var input = event.target
    if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
        input.value = 1
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText
    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
    addItemToCart(title, price)
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addItemToCart(title, price) {
    var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
    cartRow.classList.add('cart-row')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title')
    for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
            alert('This item is already added to the cart')
            return
        }
    }
    var cartRowContents = `
        <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <span class="cart-item-title">${title}</span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-price cart-column">${price}</span>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`
    cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents
    cartItems.append(cartRow)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChanged);
    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].scrollIntoView({ block: 'end',  behavior: 'smooth' });
}

function updateCartTotal() {
var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
var total = 0
for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
    var cartRow = cartRows[i]
    var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
    var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
    var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('£', ''))
    var quantity = quantityElement.value
    total = total + (price * quantity)
}
total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100
document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = '£' + total.toFixed(2)
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Is there a way of changing it so it just jumps to the basket area rather than scrolls?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, if you want it not to be smooth just remove it from: `scrollIntoView({ block: 'end',  behavior: 'smooth' });` to `scrollIntoView({ block: 'end' });` and check if that effect is what you want

Comment: How can it be changed to include the checkout total as well as the item when it scrolls down?

Comment: You can get the element of the checkout total and perform scrollIntoView on it: `document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total')[0].scrollIntoView({ block: 'end' });`

Comment: Can you edit your answer to show me where and how to put it?

Comment: Edited, I would use `btn-purchase` so that you also see that button. And you can strip off the `behavior: 'smooth'` if you don't want it.

Comment: Thanks very much for all your help.

Comment: One quick last question, How to get it to scroll to the bottom of the page?

Comment: this can be done in several ways depending on the content of your page, check the responses here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page If one solution doesn't work check another until one works for you because some of them doesn't work for nested elements or similar things

Comment: I like this one: `window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight || document.documentElement.scrollHeight);` I use it on one website, but check if you get the desired behaviour with your data

Comment: At the place you want to perform the scroll, if it's at the same moment just replace `document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].scrollIntoView({ block: 'end',  behavior: 'smooth' });` with that code. In the code snippet it won't work because it's inside an iframe and only scrolls to the end of the iframe but it should work for you

Answer (score 0):

you can use document.getElementById('yourbasket').scrollIntoView();

```js
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
    ready()
}

function ready() {
    var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
    for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    }

    var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')
    for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
        var input = quantityInputs[i]
        input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
    }

    var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-button')
    for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = addToCartButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked)
}

function purchaseClicked() {
    alert('Thank you for your purchase')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    while (cartItems.hasChildNodes()) {
        cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild)
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function removeCartItem(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    updateCartTotal()
}

function quantityChanged(event) {
    var input = event.target
    if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
        input.value = 1
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText
    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
    addItemToCart(title, price)
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addItemToCart(title, price) {
    var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
    cartRow.classList.add('cart-row')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title')
    for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
            alert('This item is already added to the cart')
            return
        }
    }
    var cartRowContents = `
        <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <span class="cart-item-title">${title}</span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-price cart-column">${price}</span>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`
    cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents
    cartItems.append(cartRow)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
    document.getElementById('yourbasket').scrollIntoView();
}

function updateCartTotal() {
var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
var total = 0
for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
    var cartRow = cartRows[i]
    var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
    var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
    var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('£', ''))
    var quantity = quantityElement.value
    total = total + (price * quantity)
}
total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100
document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = '£' + total.toFixed(2)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   
</head>
<body>

<header class="main-header">
    <nav class="main-nav nav">
    </nav>
</header>

    <div class="shop-items">
        <div class="shop-item">
            <span class="shop-item-title">Album 0</span>&nbsp;
            <div class="shop-item-details">
<span class="shop-item-price">£12.50</span>
            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO BASKET</button>
        </div>
  
<div class="shop-item">
        <span class="shop-item-title">Album 2</span>&nbsp;
        <div class="shop-item-details">
            <span class="shop-item-price">£14.50</span>
           
            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO BASKET</button>
        </div>
  
  
    <div class="shop-item">
        <span class="shop-item-title">Album 4</span>&nbsp;
        <div class="shop-item-details">
<span class="shop-item-price">£19.50</span>
        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO BASKET</button>
    </div>
    
    </div>
</section>

    <div class="shop-items">
        <div class="shop-item">
            <span class="shop-item-title">Album 6</span>&nbsp;
            <div class="shop-item-details">
<span class="shop-item-price">£19.50</span>
            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO BASKET</button>
        </div>
  
   <div class="shop-items">
        <div class="shop-item">
            <span class="shop-item-title">Album 8</span>&nbsp;
            <div class="shop-item-details">
<span class="shop-item-price">£19.50</span>
            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO BASKET</button>
        </div>
   
    
   
    </div>
</section>
<section id="yourbasket" class="container content-section">
    <h2 class="section-header">Basket</h2>
  <div class="cart-row">
        <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
        <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
        <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
    </div>
    <p></p> 
<div class="cart-items">
    </div>
    <div class="cart-total">
        <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
        <span class="cart-total-price">£0</span>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" type="button">CHECKOUT</button>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```