# Can I change CSS scroll-behavior from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I am trying to have my page snap to the top when the page is reloaded. To do this I am using JavaScript like so:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

This was working great for me until I turned on smooth scrolling in my CSS:

```
scroll-behavior: smooth;
```

And now it won't work at all.

What I'd like to be able to do is temporarily turn off the CSS smooth scrolling behavior from JS something like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   document.getElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].style.scrollBehavior = "auto";
   window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

However it looks like **style.scrollBehavior** isn't valid and I can't find anything that is. Is it possible to change this from JavaScript?

If not is there a way to turn smooth scrolling on and off from within JavaScript that is fairly simple?

*I just would like to keep things pretty straight forward if possible.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [scrollIntoView](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp) with an html element passing `smooth` as the `behaviour`, as in:

```
element.scrollIntoView({ block: 'start',  behavior: 'smooth' });
```

You can see a working example in [How to get the button when clicked go to a certain part of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736624/how-to-get-the-button-when-clicked-go-to-a-certain-part-of-the-page/60736771#60736771)