# Automatic scrolling for CSS overflow: scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I am working on a chat application and I have a background where the messages should be displayed. To not just have simple overflow I added this line to css: `overflow-y: scroll;` which will add a scroll bar. This all works fine, but is there a way to automatically scroll to the bottom, where the newest messages are. It can also be in JavaScript.

My html code looks like this:

```
<article id="chat">
    <script src="chat.js"></script>
</article>
```

Each message will have this form and gets added into the article:

```
"<p class='msg'>" + msg + "</p>"
```

Comment: Have a look at [`window.scrollBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: I don't really get what I should do, I made this code: `window.scrollTo(0,  document.querySelector("#chat").scrollHeight);`
 but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snippet changed:

```js
var targetElm = document.querySelector('.boxChild'),  // reference to scroll target
    button = document.querySelector('button');        // button that triggers the scroll
  
// bind "click" event to a button 
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
   targetElm.scrollIntoView()
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 80%;
  border: 2px dashed;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth; /* <-- for smooth scroll */
}

.boxChild {
  margin: 600px 0 300px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<button>Scroll to element</button>
<div class='box'>
  <div class='boxChild'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your post will be much improved if you could provide a code example or add additional details what OP should. Right now you only refer to a different post, which is basically a comment.

Comment: I don't really get what I should do, I made this code: `window.scrollTo(0,  document.querySelector("#chat").scrollHeight);` but it doesn't work

Comment: I tried a test so you can find something,... is that useful?

Comment: Well it is working on your example, but it doesn't work on mine. It scrolls down the whole page, but it doesn't scroll down my chat article

Comment: OK, i changed the snippet now your element should scrolls not the whole page. let me know if worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change up the answer from "so hell" a bit, since his answer only works with one message. I give every message an unique id and then scroll to that id with this command:

```
document.querySelector("#msgid" + msgId).scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: I mean I already had that kind of idea but hoped that there is a more elegant solution. But you can use the Reputation