# C# Panel AutoScroll down using chromium

Tags: winforms, panel, cefsharp, autoscroll

i have Panels, using CefSharp.WinForms, i want that every site i open, the Panel will Strating automatic down not top

[image: Exemple]

ive tried to change the panel Properties to AutoScroll - true, but its doesnt work
any help? tnx!

Comment: Winforms? WPF? Xamarin? UWP?

Comment: using CefSharp.WinForms

Comment: There's no built in functionality for this. You can use JavaScript to scroll the page, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#1-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-method-from-net https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page