# How to scroll automatically to the bottom of a page (react component) after visiting the page or updating it?

Tags: reactjs

I want to scroll automatically to the bottom of a page (component) after visiting the page (render the component) or updating it. I have tried with refs and react-scroll library but no success. Here is my code:

Using refs:

```
class CommentsDrawer extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.scrollToBottom();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.scrollToBottom();
  }

  scrollToBottom = () => {
    this.messagesEnd.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  };

  render() {
    const { show, closeDrawer } = this.props;
    let drawerClasses = styles.drawer;

    if (show) {
      drawerClasses = `${styles.drawer} ${styles.open}`;
    }

    return (
      <div className={drawerClasses}>
        <div>
          <CommentsDrawerHeader closeDrawer={closeDrawer} numOfComments={mockedData.length} />
        </div>
        <CommentsList data={mockedData} />
        {/* TODO: Reply functionality is just a mockup for this task scope. To be fully implemented in the integration task. */}
        <CommentInput />
        <div ref={(el) => { this.messagesEnd = el; }} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll Automatically to the Bottom of the Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to create the reference in the constructor of the component. I have made the implementation in the child component which renders the comments.

```
mport React, { Component, createRef } from "react";
import { array, func, boolean } from "prop-types";
import Comment from "../Comment/Comment";

import styles from "./CommentsList.scss";

class CommentsList extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/forbid-prop-types
    data: array.isRequired,
    sendReply: func,
    deleteReply: func,
    show: boolean
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    sendReply: () => {},
    deleteReply: () => {},
    show: true
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.bottomRef = createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.scrollToBottom();
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    if (!this.props.show) {
      this.scrollToBottom();
    }
  }

  scrollToBottom = () => {
    this.bottomRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  };

  render() {
    const { data, sendReply, deleteReply } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={styles.comments__list}>
        {data.map(el => (
          <Comment
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
            key={el._id}
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
            id={el._id}
            by={el.by}
            jobTitle={el.jobTitle}
            timestamp={el.at}
            comment={el.comment}
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
            replyTo={!_.isUndefined(el.replyTo) && el.replyTo}
            origin={el.origin}
            sendReply={sendReply}
            deleteReply={deleteReply}
          />
        ))}
        <div ref={this.bottomRef} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CommentsList;
```