# How do I set the view to the page's bottom on entering the page?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

I have a page that represents a chat in my Angular-Ionic project. When the user opens the chat, I would like the view to already be scrolled all the way down to the latest message.

I have tried using `ionContent.scrollToBottom(0)` in a `setTimeout` (since the content doesn't load right away) but it's pretty awkward: it very briefly shows the top of the messages and then teleports to the bottom, making it look super ugly.

I am using Angular 10 and Ionic 5.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: This might help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Comment: I'd still use Ionic's scrollToBottom and show a loader if the pause bothers you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.onload = function() {window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);}`.

Hope it helped!