# how to auto scroll down when new messages added

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I am working with django , I want to scroll down auto when new messages added 'sent or received', I can scroll down auto when I refrech the page because of this code line :

```
$("#card-body").animate({ scrollTop: 20000000 }, "slow");
```

but when I send and I receive new messages the messages go down until I can't see them I have to scroll down manually
this is the js code :

```
    <script>

        /* send message*/
        document.getElementById('send-btn-id').onclick = function (e) {
            const msg = document.getElementById('message').value;
            chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
                'message': msg,
                'user': me,
                'friend': friendName
            }));
            document.getElementById('message').value = "";
            
        };

        const friendName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('friend').textContent);
        const me = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('me').textContent);

        /* set friend profile name */
        document.getElementById('friend-name').innerHTML = friendName['username'];

        /* start conversation */
        document.querySelector('.start-conversation').innerHTML = 'Start conversation with <strong>'+friendName['username']+'</strong>';

        /* connection request */
        const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
            'ws://'
            + window.location.host
            + '/ws/chat/'
            + friendName['username']
            + '/'
        );

        chatSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
            const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            var class_name = 'in';
            var profile_image = '{{friend_obj.profile.image.url}}';

            if(me['username'] == data.user['username']) {
                data.user['username'] = 'Me';
                class_name = 'out';
                profile_image = '{{request.user.profile.image.url}}';
            }

            var chat_list = document.querySelector('#chat-list-id');
            var chat = "<li class=\""+class_name+"\"><div class=\"chat-img\"><img alt=\"avatarchat\" src=\""+profile_image+"\"></div><div class=\"chat-body\"><div class=\"chat-message\"><h5>"+data.user['username']+"</h5><p>"+data.message+"</p></div></div></li>";
            
            chat_list.innerHTML += chat;
        };
        
    </script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page/68874831#68874831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this easily, you can do the following:

```javascript
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)

### **WHAT YOU SHOULD NOT DO**

```javascript
window.scrollTo(0, 9999);
```

Even though the number is big, sometimes webpages can be **VERY** large.

### **BACK TO CONTENT**

If you want it to scroll smoothly, then you can set this css property:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Working example:

```js
const btmG = document.querySelector("#btm-good");
const btmB = document.querySelector("#btm-bad");

window.onload = () => {
  btmG.onclick = () => {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  };

  btmB.onclick = () => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 9999);
  };
}
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<button id="btm-good"> Scroll to bottom (not 9999) </button>

<button id="btm-bad"> Scroll to bottom (is 9999) </button>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Wait a sec, this isn't the bottom...<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    
Hi
```

Answer (score 1):

hello guys thanks to you I have found the solution and I want to share it with you and it works actually,so really thank you :
I thought that I can actually make this code line in the send, hold on you will understand after watching the code :
I have mentioned this before right

```
$("#card-body").animate({ scrollTop: 20000000 }, "slow");
```

and this one either :

```
/* send message*/
        document.getElementById('send-btn-id').onclick = function (e) {
            const msg = document.getElementById('message').value;
            chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
                'message': msg,
                'user': me,
                'friend': friendName
            }));
            document.getElementById('message').value = "";
            
        };
```

so after watching your answers I think to put the line in the **//send message** like this :

```
/* send message*/
        document.getElementById('send-btn-id').onclick = function (e) {
            const msg = document.getElementById('message').value;
            chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
                'message': msg,
                'user': me,
                'friend': friendName
            }));
            document.getElementById('message').value = "";
            $("#card-body").animate({ scrollTop: 20000000 }, "slow");
        };
```

my english is not fine but the code works, I hope it helps someone facing same problem.