# Automatically start scrolling when opened my website

Tags: javascript, scroll, autoscroll

Is there any way by which I can use a feature- "slowly auto scroll to the bottom" when a visitor opens my website
(I want that when a visitor visits/open my website then the page should slowly start scrolling to the bottom)
If any way is there then please tell me and I don't need way in which visitor have to click on button, I want a way in which automatically start scrolling when the website is opened

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll Automatically to the Bottom of the Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Answer (score 1):

Your question might get misinterpreted so I just want to say this: You shouldn't control user's scroll position for them.

It's just bad UX in my opinion and it is also not very good for accessiblity.

Yes it's possible to do it using [window.scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll) function. If you want it to be smooth or animated,  you'll have to implement it yourself by using `timeOut` but it's not going to be perfect.

What are you actually trying to achieve? Some kind of scrolling effect? I've seen some sites that appear to move downwards but that's completely different technique (combination of JavaScript and CSS).