# Is it possible to write a bookmarklet that repeatedly jumps to the end of page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, bookmarklet

Is it possible to write a bookmarklet that repeatedly jumps to the end of page in the background?

I want to scroll down "all the way" on Facebook. Currently I have to do it manually by sending End-of-page multiple times. I would like to do that automatically and in the background (i.e. I can continue browse in another window or tab while my Facebook tab scrolls down).

Comment: Please show your current code

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I don't know Javascript.

Comment: just to be sure: scraping is not allowed on facebook, if that is what you want to do.

Comment: @andyrandy No. I would use Selenium for that.

Comment: selenium = scraping. which is not allowed ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)

you can use this code to scroll to the bottom of the page

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
```

if you wrap it in a setInterval, you can make it repeat
this might work

```
javascript:setInterval(window.scrollTo, 1000, 0, document.body.scrollHeight)
```

Comment: That looked very promising, but when I make a bookmarklet of it (in Firefox) and click it, it replaces the content of the page with a number. can you fix that? If so, I will mark it at the accepted answer. It would also be great if it allowed me to set the number of repetitions (e.g., 10 - that is, "end of page" 10 times and wait 2 seconds after each "end of page" to allow for loading more content) in the bookmarklet.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is but if Firefox is loading a number there is a fix for it.
you can fix the number problem by just adding something like Console.log(":)") to the end of it. if Firefox is causing the issue than I cant solve it, I don't have Firefox

Comment: What is the exact syntax for that?

Comment: `javascript:setInterval(window.scrollTo, 1000, 0, document.body.scrollHeight);Console.log(":)")`

Comment: That worked! And how do you make it repeat 10 times with 1 second delay between repetitions?

Comment: you can put it in a self calling funtion like so
`javascript:scrollnum = 0;function scroll10() {window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);scrollnum++;if(scrollnum < 10) {setTimeout(scroll10, 1000)}};scroll10();Console.log(":)");` hopefully that should work