# Inverse Scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm working on a messaging app with React and in the conversation section with another user I want the scrollbar (to navigate between messages) to be displayed by default at the bottom so that it always shows the last message received and the user doesn't have to navigate to the most recent message when opening the chat.

[image: here´s a example (whatsapp web)]

I've been searching and reviewing but I haven't found anything useful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page